# es2016 handling callbacks in class constructor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to write the following code into a es2015 class syntax:

```
export function initialize(port) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const application = express();
        const server = application.listen(port, function listening(error) {
            if (error) reject(error);
            resolve(server);
        });
    });
}
const server = async initialize(port);
```

es2015:

```
class Server {
    constructor(port) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const application = express();
            const server = application.listen(port, function listening(error) {
                if (error) reject(error);
                resolve(server);
            });
        });
    }
}
const server = async new Server(port); // <-- not a good idea!
```

Apparently returning and a `Promise` is not such a good idea when using the `new` which should return an instant instance. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you mean `await` instead of `async` after `const server =`?

Comment: "*I'm trying to write the following code into a es2015 class syntax*" - why? There's no point in doing that. It doesn't even work as you noticed. The `function` is much simpler. What was your goal?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a separate `initialise` method and call that from instance:

```
class Server {
  constructor(port) {
    this.port = port;
  }

  initialise() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const application = express();
      const server = application.listen(this.port, function listening(error) {
        if (error) reject(error);
        resolve(server);
      });
    });
  }
}
const server = new Server(port);
server.initialise().then(() => // do some stuff)
```

Comment: What's the advantage of doing that? It's not like you can reuse `serverInstance` by calling `initialise()` a second time or so.

Comment: This avoids creating a promise in constructor.

Comment: Sure, I mean it's even a good solution for that, but what's the advantage of using a `class Server` over the original code?